# Why Does NOT YouTube Data API Work Locally?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I spent *countless* hours on this error but couldn't figure it out. I'm using the YouTube API to retrieve videos based on a search query. **In the browser, when I search for localhost:3000/yt, it shows this message:**
[image]

**The server-side code is shown below:**

```js
    app.get('/yt', async (req, res) => {
    const auth = await authenticate({
    keyfilePath: "/Users/hendy/Desktop/Dev/HCI-Summer-Research/EduRec/system/oauth2.keys.json",
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
  });
     google.options({auth});

  const result = await youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    q: 'Node.js on Google Cloud',
  });
  res.send(result.data);
})

  app.listen(3000);
```

**The OAuth setup from Google Console is shown below. The JSON file that contains this info and my secret and client ID keys is in my project folder.**

[image]

**And this is the API setup:**

[image]

Comment: have you considered following https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

If you click on error details it will tell you exactly what redirect uri you need to set.

The redirect uri must exactly match the one you are sending from

I have a YouTube video that shows you exactly how to fix that error [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

My question is if you are doing this from localhost and dont intend to host it on a web server why didn't you just create installed app credentials why are you working with web credentials?

Comment: Every time I run my application on the browser, an authentication tab opens telling me that authentication was successful. I intend to deploy this application and don't want this page to pop up frequently. Is there any way to set an expiration time for that API?

Comment: Every time I run my application on the browser, an authentication tab opens telling me that authentication was successful. I intend to deploy this application and don't want this page to pop up frequently. Is there any way to set an expiration time for that API?

Comment: Store the refresh token and use it again the next time the user comes to your page.    The sample for google drive shows how to do it.  But the auth code is for an installed app  https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/quickstart/nodejs  your going to have to merge this some how.  Not sure If i have a sample for this laying around.